# Will Allah forgive me for what was done to me?

Tags: halal-haram, forgiveness

I feel so guilty for falling into a sin that was out of my control because someone took advantage of me and I want ask for forgiveness from Allah (SWT). Will he still be able to forgive me for this sin? How do I seek forgiveness for this kind of sin? I want to be a better Muslim in the future and I feel terrible for what was done to me.

Comment: This is added information: And also he is close relative to our family but I can’t tell my parents because it would be really bad and so I am worried about my future.

Answer (score 0):

In Islam no matter how many sins you have done, when you ask Allah for forgiveness from heart honestly He forgives. And Islam forbids sharing your sins with other humans in any case. Even if your sins are more than all the waters of earth Allah will forgive them the moment you quit doing sins and ask for forgiveness.

Even if you slip again after seeking forgiveness never never get disappointed from Allah, he is greater beyond your sins and expectations. The key to success is come back to Allah as soon as possible every time.

But be warned you will be at loss if you make it hobby and a cycle of sin and forgiveness as definitely that won't be honest forgiveness.

Comment: Thank you that makes me feel much better becuase I don’t want to ever do this again and be a good Muslim thank you☺️